# Cambiar los valores de tiempo de formato HHMM a HH:MM en python

Tags: python, datetime, formato, time

Soy nueva en python. Mi código trata de leer un archivo de datos ('20071018_G10xr_1m.txt') como se muestra a continuación:

```
#Time     
#HHMM     Short    Long
#--------------------------
0000   3.45e-09  3.73e-09
0001   3.45e-09  3.73e-09
0002   3.45e-09  3.73e-09
0003   3.45e-09  3.73e-09
...
0059   3.44e-09  3.73e-09
0100   3.49e-09  3.73e-09
0101   3.44e-09  3.73e-09
...
2357   3.44e-09  3.73e-09
2358   3.44e-09  3.73e-09
2359   3.44e-09  3.73e-09
```

Es un archivo de un día de datos. El código que escribí para graficarlo tiene por objetivo el de ver como evoluciona el logaritmo de "Short" con respecto al tiempo. Mi código es el siguiente:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from datetime import datetime

#Lectura de los archivos GOES
data_GOES = open('20071018_G10xr_1m.txt').readlines()
d_GOES = data_GOES[3:]

time = []
label_1 = []
label_2 = []

for line in d_GOES:
    p = line.split()
    time.append(int(p[0]))
    label_1.append(float(p[2]))

time_GOES = np.array(time)
print time_GOES
time_format_2 = [str(timedelta(minutes=s)) for s in time_GOES]
print time_format_2
t_format_2 = '%H:%M:%S'
date_GOES = [datetime.strptime(i, t_format_2).time() for i in time_format_2]
print date_GOES
label_1_GOES = np.array(label_1)

plt.semilogy(date_GOES, label_1_GOES, color='blue')
plt.legend(['GOES Xray Flux'])
plt.xlabel('Tiempo UTC')
plt.ylabel(r'X-ray Flux ($Watts/m^{2}$)')
plt.show()
```

Al momento de ejecutarlo, el tiempo se muestra de la siguiente forma:

```
['00:01' '00:02' ... '00:59' '1:40:00' '1:41:00' ... '3:00:00' ... '1 day 00:05']
```

En lugar de que me muestre la forma de deseo que aparezca en la gráfica:

```
['00:00' '00:01' '00:02' '00:03' '00:04' '00:05' ... '23:59']
```

Que debo modificar en el código o aumentar para que el eje del tiempo (x) tenga la forma deseada.

Por si acaso estoy utilizando el Python 2.7.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que en la línea en que haces:

```
time_format_2 = [str(timedelta(minutes=s)) for s in time_GOES]
```

estás forzando a que los números que vienen en `s` se interpreten como minutos.

Los primeros valores te van saliendo bien, pues "0015" por ejemplo, te daría 15 como valor para `s`, y eso pasado a un timedelta en el que `s` represente minutos, te da 15 minutos, que es correcto.

Pero tan pronto como alcanzas el valor "0100", que debería ser una hora y cero minutos, estás haciendo `s=100` y por tanto creando un timedelta de 100 minutos, que es 1:40 como python correctamente te calcula.

Lo que tienes que hacer es **no** convertir el primer campo del fichero a entero, sino dejarlo como cadena, y después convertir esa cadena en una hora válida mediante:

```
strptime(primer_campo, "%H%M")
```

Aquí le dices a Python que interprete el primer campo como una hora "pegada" a unos minutos. Una vez obtenido un objeto datetime válido por este método, ya puedes extraer sólo la hora usando `.time()` como hacías en tu código.

De paso, algunas sugerencias de mejora sobre el código:

- Has olvidado cerrar el fichero. Para que no se te olvide nunca, se recomienda usar "contextos" (bloques que comienzan por `with open(...) as f:`) pues en cuanto salgas del contexto Python cerrará el fichero `f` por ti.
- Es ineficiente usar `readlines()`, pues carga todas las líneas en memoria, lo que dependiendo del tamaño del fichero puede ser un problema. Para iterar por las líneas del fichero puedes usar directamente `for linea in fichero`, pues eso va leyendo las líneas de una en una sin necesidad de guardarlas todas en memoria para luego iterar por ellas como tú hacías.
- En lugar de saltarte las tres primeras líneas del fichero de forma prefijada, es más flexible saltarse las líneas vacías o las que comiencen por `#`, como muestro más adelante.
- A medida que procesas las líneas, puedes ir convirtiendo el primer campo a un objeto `datetime` apropiado, con el formato `"%H%M"` que antes comenté.

Con todas estas ideas, la parte de lectura de fichero quedaría así:

```
time = []
label_1 = []
# label_2 = []    # Esta no la usabas
t_format = '%H%M'

#Lectura de los archivos GOES
with open('20071018_G10xr_1m.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip() or line.startswith("#"):
          continue
        p = line.split()
        time.append(datetime.strptime(p[0], t_format).time())
        label_1.append(float(p[2]))

date_GOES = np.array(time)
label_1_GOES = np.array(label_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

@abulafia indica correctamente en su respuesta los fallos que tienes en tu código y como parsear la columna con la hora, no voy a incidir en ello. Dado que importas Pandas, aunque no lo uses, puedes usar `pandas.read_csv` para parsear tu archivo, lo que simplifica en mi opinión mucho la tarea y te evitas trabajar con listas. En esencia tienes un csv con espacios como separador y con algunas filas que son comentarios:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('20071018_G10xr_1m.txt', 
                 sep="\s+",
                 comment="#",
                 names=("HHMM", "Short", "Long"), 
                 date_parser=lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%H%M').time(),
                 parse_dates=[0]
                 )


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x="HHMM", y="Short", color='blue', ax=ax)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.legend(['GOES Xray Flux'])
ax.set_xlabel('Tiempo UTC')
ax.set_ylabel(r'X-ray Flux ($Watts/m^{2}$)')
plt.show()
```

Para parsear la hora se usa una función lambda que usa el formato `%H%M` para obtener un objeto `datetime` y luego eliminamos la información de la fecha usando el método `time()`.

El dataframe que genera es algo así:

> ```
>        HHMM         Short          Long
> 0  00:00:00  3.450000e-09  3.730000e-09
> 1  00:01:00  3.450000e-09  3.730000e-09
> 2  00:02:00  3.450000e-09  3.730000e-09
> 3  00:03:00  3.450000e-09  3.730000e-09
> 4  00:04:00  3.440000e-09  3.730000e-09
> 5  00:05:00  3.490000e-09  3.730000e-09
> 6  00:06:00  3.440000e-09  3.730000e-09
> 7  00:07:00  3.440000e-09  3.730000e-09
> 8  00:08:00  3.440000e-09  3.730000e-09
> 9  00:09:00  3.440000e-09  3.730000e-09
> ```

Si no te interesa la columna `Long`, ignorala al leer el archivo usando el argumento `usecols`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('20071018_G10xr_1m.txt', 
                 sep="\s+",
                 comment="#",
                 names=("HHMM", "Short", "Long"), 
                 date_parser=lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%H%M').time(),
                 parse_dates=[0], 
                 usecols=[0, 1]
                 )
```

Si no te resulta cómodo usar `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, puedes usar matplotlib directamente como tu haces:

```
plt.semilogy(df["HHMM"], df["Short"], color='blue')
```